# Facebook share in iOS with the new updated API's in v2.9

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-share

Can anybody help me in the iOS Facebook sharing. I am now unable to share an image with link. And I went to Facebook change logs and they stated there that for FBSDKShareLinkContent you cannot use "contentTitle", "imageURL", "contentDescription".
Anybody knows how to share to Facebook through new SDK.

Thanks!

Comment: All this meta data will be taken from the Open Graph meta tags the URL that is shared returns. Facebook is removing all ways to specify this data dynamically at the time of sharing.

Comment: @CBroe so, you are saying that there is no way now. After this SDK update we will be unable to share image with title and description, not even by Graph API?

Comment: No; you will just not be able to specify them _dynamically_ any more.

Comment: Oh!! that's bad. Thank you for your reply, still looking forward for other answers.

Comment: I don’t think you’ll get any different answers, because as I said Facebook is deliberately removing this, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations

Comment: Thank you for the link, now I got a more clear picture about this but What is 90-Day Deprecations?. Is it only be available for 90 days or something like that?

Comment: No, it means this will be the case for all API versions, 90 days after the introduction date of API v2.9 (which was April 18th, 2017, so that plus 90 days gets you somewhere in the middle of June, when this will stop working in all API versions < 2.9 as well.)